# Preserving object reference after "new"

Tags: c#, reference

I'm trying to, in essence, cheaply reference a base object so that it can be built fully later on and be easily referenceable by anything not directly involved within the building process of that object. However, when I have an object that makes sense to construct during the build process (its actually a factory that creates other objects that use a that are reliant on "a" and it makes sense to build these objects within the switch case.)

I've considered using pointers but I don't think they'll be appropriate.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class ClassA
    {
        public virtual void hello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }

    class ClassB : ClassA
    {
        public override void hello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye World!");
        } 
    }

    class ClassC
    {
        ClassA m_object;

        public ClassC(ClassA a)
        {
            m_object = a;
        }
        public void run()
        {
            m_object.hello();
            Console.WriteLine(m_object.GetType().ToString());
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassA a;

            ClassC c = new ClassC(a);

            //switch(something)
            //{
                //case "somethingElse":
                    a = new ClassB();
                    c.run();
                    //...
                //break;
            //...
            //}
            //CompleteAGenericCollationTaskWith(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically:

I'm trying to: Pass a shared reference of an object before it's created, to an object, so that I can have (preferably) read-only access from it from inside that second object.

I suspect it has something to do with `a = new ClassB();` overwriting the reference but I'm only about 60% sure it's the case and have no idea how to preserve it without using pointers.

Question:

How do I make this work? Do I need to change my structure(likely)? Can I do this while maintaining `ClassA` and `ClassB` with minimal changes to `ClassC` and `Program`?

Comment: Can't you just place the assignment of `c` after the `switch`? At that point, you are going to have `a` properly instantiated.

Comment: I'm adding generic objects that are dependant on `a` within `c` - `c` is a factory class that looks at some of the properties of `a` to help build validators for it - some validators (such as date validators) are specific to date controls whereas a required field validator would be free (and expected -) to be created after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the page on references in MSDN, it explains how to do this very verbosely: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Having said that, while the 'ref' keyword will solve this specific problem without modifying too much code, it reeks of bad coding style to reference a not-yet-instantiated object. You should probably refactor the code to correctly respect instantiation order, for example by passing the instance of ClassB to the 'run' method of c.

Comment: I did try using ref, but after another new statement the reference is lost/broken. I would honestly do what you've suggested, but adding this to every case in a massive switch case smells just as bad.

Comment: If the code needs it, it needs it. When you have 300 switch cases that do something slightly different, write the slightly different ones, don't try to hack it away. Or make a proper helper function out of it that eliminates the identical parts.

Comment: Fair comment, I'll give other people some time to come up with a different solution- but I'll accept after a few hours if they can't.